# Align text on top of a framebox

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes, framed

I am trying to create a series of boxes so that my students can input there id number for there final exam.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\idbox}
\sbox{\idbox}{\framebox[4.5mm]{\vrule depth 1.25mm width 0pt height 2.5mm}}
\newcommand{\nidbox}[1]{%
\foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
{
\usebox{\idbox}\kern-1.5pt
}}
\begin{document}
\nidbox{5}
\end{document}
```

What I want is to be able to put ID Number directly aligned on top of the first framebox and to be left justified. I have been trying to use `\raisebox` like:

```
\def\idnum#1{\raisebox{0.8\baselineskip}[1ex][2ex]{%
ID NUMBER}\kern-4cm #1}
```

where its implementation would be like `\idnum{\nidbox{5}}`.

Sincerely I do not know if it is the best approach but I believe that I am forcing it. I know that I can probably do it using a table or with an array but am trying to find out a different approach. Any insights into the matter will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Question: Is it inappropriate the `\raisebox` attempt that I was using in my code above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer `expl3` to `tikz` for repeating things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\idbox}{}
  {
   \framebox[4.5mm]{\vrule depth 1.25mm width 0pt height 2.5mm}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\idnum}{m}
  {
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
   ID~Number\\
   \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \idbox \hspace{3pt} }
   \end{tabular}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\idnum{5}

\idnum{7}
\end{document}
```

A `tabular` environment is just the more convenient way to align objects. A `tabular` free macro could be

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\idnum}{ m }
  {
   \vbox:n
     {
      \hbox:n { \strut ID~Number }
      \hbox:n { \strut\prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \idbox \hspace{3pt} } \unskip }
     }
  }
```

But I don't see why one should prefer this approach to the simplicity of a `tabular`.

[image]

Comment: You have the luxury to prefer one to the other, we mortals can only know a few things at once :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for though I was looking for a non-table code. Much appreciated though. Thanks again

Comment: @azetina What's the problem with a `tabular`?

Comment: @egreg Nothing really am just looking for other ways of doing it. For most stuff I resort to tikz or tabular environments but am trying to find alternatives.

Comment: @azetina A `tabular` is *really* the way to go in this case.

Comment: @egreg I do agree with you. Myself, I couldn't find other better alternatives other than the suggestions presented here.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a short non-TikZ solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\fboxsep8pt
\fboxrule0pt
\@for \next:=A,B,C,D,E\do{
 \fbox{\next}%
}

\vspace{-3pt}
\fboxrule1pt
\fboxsep7pt
\@for \next:=A,B,C,D,E\do{
 \fbox{\color{white}\next}%
}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

It will also work if you change the `\@for` to `\@tfor` as follows:

```
\@tfor \next:=ABCDE\do{
 \fbox{\color{white}\next}%
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's all Yiannis' fault by mentioning 'non-TikZ' solution :-) Here is a TikZ solution...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[count=\xi] \x in {A,...,F}
{
\node[label={[inner sep=1mm]90:\x},draw,inner sep=3mm] (\x) at (\xi,0) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Positioning can be changed via modifying `at (\xi,0)` with `at (0.8*\xi,0)` and similarly box sizes can be changed by the second `inner sep` option. (First defines the distance of the letters from the box.)

Comment: I love tikz but am looking for alternatives other than it. But thanks for your input